# STM32F031 HSI clock temperature impact

Tags: stm32, clock, temperature, pll

I developed an electrical board that contains a STM32F31C4T6. The product worked well for more than two but since this summer I have customer feedback on malfunctions of the card, it no longer works at all. When the baffle is found, simply disconnect and reconnect the board for which function.

Following the finding of this defect, I set up a test procedure to try to reproduce the defect. In this procedure there is a temperature test phase at 85°C and it is during this stage that the product is stopped, so I followed this track. For the product to restart it is necessary to wait for the temperature to drop and unplug then reconnect the power necessarily because the one does not restart automatically. After that I dug on the µC program side and I found that the clock system was configured on 48MHz with the HSI multiplied by a PLL. So I did the tests by changing the frequency to 16MHz and the product works at 95°C without problems.

It is therefore to clarify the technical causes of the problem that I am posting here. I would like technical explanations on the cause of the problem. The first intuition I found was this:

"If the accuracy of the internal oscillator is changed beyond the tolerance band (1% around the theoretical value) due to temperature or other conditions, the bootloader may calculate an incorrect HSE frequency value. The wrong HSE value is then used for the calculation of the PLL parameters. The CPU and CPU peripherals will then run at an unexpected frequency."

Comment: Unplug what to make it work again? Power, some UART cable, or USB perhaps? You quote the bootloader; so is this about your program or the bootloader that does not work? How does the bootloader fit into the picture, are you even running it if your own firmware is running? So can you be more specific, when it stops working, what does it mean? Fails to communicate properly over UART perhaps?

Comment: The STM32F031C4T**6** has a maximum operating temperature spec of 85°C. That's the max allowed temperature of the silicon die in the device. If you're using it in a 85°C ambient environment, then the device internal temperature will be higher - thus violating the max temperature operating spec. If you need to operate at such a high temperature then you'll probably need to switch to using a STM32F031C4T**7** instead, which is spec'ed to operate up to 105°C.

Comment: @Justme To be clearer, my product installs in a car and is powered by the car's 12V battery. Once my fault appears at high temperature and the temperature drops, the board remains in the fault. To get the board working again, I have to disconnect the battery powering the board and reconnect it. I can only do this if the temperature is low, because if I disconnect and reconnect the card while the environment is still hot, the card will go back into fault.

Comment: @brhans I completely agree with you, but that doesn't justify why the STM32F031C4T6 works so well at 95°C with a 16MHz clock system.

Comment: @Kolia so do you use CAN? I mean, what gets stuck or fault condition? It will help determine  what the problem is. So what interfaces you use, do you not have a crystal, and have you debugged what gets stuck?

Comment: Halving the clock frequency puts less stress on the PLL, so you have a bit more wiggle-room on exceeding the temperature spec.

Comment: Do you use watchdog? You should. If you use, which one? IWDG or WWDG or both?